# Manually change filetype icons in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, icons, file-types

I'm trying to find the dialog tab in Windows 7 that allows a user to change the icon used for a particular file type.

In Windows XP it would be under the Folder Options properties dialog.

[image: folder options dialog from Windows XP]

Where is it on Windows 7?

I only want to change the icon of a specific filetype, to anything I want but this tab is no longer present in Folder Options of Windows 7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use *File Type Manager* - check this link from [www.howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12383/change-a-file-types-icon-in-windows-7/) for a step-by-step procedure.

Or you can choose the hard way to change the registry (not recommended though): [How to Change the Icon for a File Type in Windows 7 and Vista](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/change-file-type-icon-windows-7-and-vista/)

Comment: Great, got it working with that File Types Manager: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html

Comment: I've used this to differentiate .png and .jpg file types, but whatever changes I make effect them both. Any idea why?

Comment: @TommyMyron, because this answer provide solution which change default icon for filetype run-application and **not** directly for filetype. Namely, you change icon association provided by `Progid` of filetype (more accurately, you change icon for all filetypes which are opened by default prog of the filetype).

Answer (score 4):

Please see the bottom section labeled "**UPDATE**". I left the top half to preserve the information.

I believe [ths](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560745%28WS.10%29.aspx) is the page you are looking for. Below is quoted information from that page. Microsoft did move a lot of stuff around in Windows 7 compared to XP, so for the exact part of the window where you are finding registered file types, this will do.

> To find the registered file types on a
>   computer running Windows Vista or
>   Windows 7
>
> 1. Click Start. Open Control Panel, click Control Panel Home in Windows
>      Vista, and click Programs.
> 2. Click Default Programs, and click Associate a file type or protocol with
>      a program.
> 3. On this screen, the registered file types are displayed.
>
> For more information about how to
>   change the file types, files, and
>   folders that are migrated when you
>   specify the MigUser.xml file, see
>   Using USMT.

Below is a screenshot of the window.
[image]

**UPDATE**

It seems that the first part did not work. Here is a way that is supposed to work. I did not test it, I just read a lot about it. [This](http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/24442-change-default-icon-file-type.html) page showed a couple ways of completing the desired task. Both ways unfortunately require purchasing a program.

- [File Extension Icon - Change Default Icon](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/57455-file-extension-icon-change-default-icon.html)
- [Icon Packager](http://www.stardock.com/products/IconPackager/)

You might be able to download the free trial and change only what you want and uninstall the program. Hopefully that would cause the changes to be permanent due to the program making registry changes.

Please note that I am only trying to name easy ways.

Comment: i cant still find the button where i change the filetype icon... i can only change the program which it uses to open them.

Comment: Sorry about that @winuser. I am going to look into it a little more. I just half way tested it by getting to the screen and taking the screenshot. I thought it looked correct, so I posted it.

Comment: I think I found a good answer. I am updating the answer right now.

Answer (score 3):

[FileTypesMan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) is free and helps you change the icons easily:

1. Select the extension
2. Press F2 to edit the type
3. Browse to a .exe or .dll file to select an icon

Comment: Excellent solution. Should be the main answer.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately doing this in Windows 7 involves editing the registry.

[Default Program Editor](https://defaultprogramseditor.com/) will do it. It's lightweight, freeware, and a standalone executable (no installation). It also allows you to edit the right-click menu per file type and perform a couple other file type-specific actions.