# How do I change the icon for PDFs in Win 7

Tags: windows-7

My Adobe Elements PDFs files show a blank white page icon. How do I change the icon that shows for PDFs files in Windows 7?

Comment: Use this as reference http://superuser.com/questions/301226/manually-change-filetype-icons-in-windows-7

Comment: Also see: [Adobe PDF icon disappeared?](http://superuser.com/questions/127857/adobe-pdf-icon-disappeared)

Answer (score 2):

For changing all the icons of a particular file type just follow these steps...

1. To change the icon of a particular file type you need to have a ".ico" file. If you already have it then go to "step 3" or else you need to download or save your preferred image to your computer first. It must be in ".jpg" or ".png" format.
2. Now go to google and search "converticon". Head to converticon.com and click on get started. Select your downloaded image to open it and click on "Export". Now it's better to select all the boxes and uncheck the original size box so that you have a proper icon file for all view types. Then just save it.
3. Go back to google and search "filetypesman". The first link to show up will be of "nirsoft.com" which is the software producing company's homepage. Go to that link, scroll down and click on download. It's a small .zip file of about 62KB.
4. Extract the .zip file and open the "filetypesman.exe" file.
5. Go to "Edit\Find" or directly press "Ctrl+f".
6. Select the file type that you want to change (i.e. ".mp3", ".mp4", ".avi", ".pdf" or any other file type that you want) and click on find next or press enter. (If you do not see the searched file type in the background then click on find next again). When you see your searched file type close this "Find" window.
7. Right click on your desired file type and go to "Edit Selected File Type" or you can simply press F2.
8. Now in "Default Icon" give the address of your saved icon file or click on the small box on the right side and then browse to that .ico file and open it. Click on ok and close the program.

You will now have a changed default icon for the specific file type.

*Note: To view the changed icon of files that generate thumbnails you need to disable thumbnail. For this go to "Folder Options" under "Appearance and Personalization" in control Panel and under the "View" tab check the box "Always show icons, never thumbnails" and apply it. (This step may be required for image, video and pdf files).*

Comment: Why go through this long process when Windows handles this natively?

Comment: T'is the only process I know of.

Comment: vembutech tells us how to change the icon of the program itself rather than that of the file.

Answer (score 1):

To change the icon of a application, simply right-click on the icon and select 'Properties'.

Go to Shortcut tab > click the Change Icon button > now, choose one of the other available icons or click browse to find the icon you want.

[image]

Comment: That's only changing the icon used for that particular shortcut.